# jquery toggle() on DIV by hiding other div's

Tags: jquery, function, click, toggle, slidetoggle

I am using the following code to toggle the div by clicking on the block heading. I need to make the respective div appear on the click of respective block headings. Also those div should toggle by themselves.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    a { color:#C30; text-decoration:none; }
    #banner { width: 930px; background-color:#666; height: 500px; }
    #banner ul { list-style:none; padding: 40px; }
    #banner ul li { margin: 10px 0 0 0; }
    #banner ul li a { display:inline-block; border:5px solid #fff; background-color:#FC9; padding:10px; font: bold italic 18px Verdana; }
    .sliderContent { border:5px solid #fff; background-color:#FC9; padding:10px; min-height: 150px; display:none; margin-top:5px; }
    .sliderContent a { padding:0 !important; border:none !important; }
    .sliderContent a.closeButton { background:url(icon_modal_close.png) no-repeat 0 0; float:right; height:30px; width:30px; text-indent:-999px; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.box').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).next('.sliderContent').toggle(function() {
                $('.sliderContent').not(this).hide();
            });
        });
        $('.closeButton').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().hide();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="banner">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="box">Design</a>
            <div class="sliderContent">
                <a class="closeButton" href="#">Close</a>
                Lorem Ipsum Doner
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="box">Development</a>
            <div class="sliderContent">
                <a class="closeButton" href="#">Close</a>
                Lorem Ipsum Doner
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="box">Graphics</a>
            <div class="sliderContent">
                <a class="closeButton" href="#">Close</a>
                Lorem Ipsum Doner
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the problem is with DIV hide() function. toggle function executes first then hide() function comes into picture. It makes my layout distorted as at a time two div are shown on the screen for a moment.

It should be like div will hide first then current div will appear.

Please help me on the same.

Thanks
Lokesh Yadav

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.box').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var sliderContent = $(this).next('.sliderContent');
            $('.sliderContent').not(sliderContent).hide();
            sliderContent.toggle();
        });
        $('.closeButton').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().hide();
        });
    });
```

here the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/JtSsM/5/

Comment: it works like charm :)   thanks a lot for saving my life alex :)

Comment: client requirement is changed, now what i am trying to do is if i click the block then that box itself get expanded. Rather animating that box, i removed the border bottom of li block. Please suggest me the right approach to make it like the block itself get exaonded on click. you can check live code what i did http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/Jvuqa/